# string comparison in a bash script

Tags: bash, nagios

This one's got me scratching my head.  I have a bash script I'm trying to run as a nagios plugin.

From the command line all is well but when running under nagios the wrong execution path is taken.  The nagios server in this case is my local box.

This is where things go wrong in the script.  It's a little simplified but not much.  Sample:

```
# at the start of the script
threshold_type="above"

# then later on..

check_thresholds() {
    if [ "$threshold_type" == "above" ]; then
        method_1
    else
        method_2
    fi
}
```

When `check_thresholds` is called `method_2` runs under nagios.  Running from the command line (same arguments, I swear) `method_1` is called.  Any ideas what might be going on?  Should I check string comparison differently?

[Edit] I foolishly neglected to mention that the command line is run from a Mac OSX, while the nagios server is an Ubuntu VM on the box.

Comment: The error is consistent with a value of `threshold_type` that is modified. Is there any chance the script on the Ubuntu VM has DOS line endings, which would put a stray carriage return at the end of `threshold_type`'s value. That would cause the comparison to fail and `method_2` to be called.

Comment: @chepner not impossible, I'll double check that, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ "$threshold_type" == "above" ]
```

is a bad mixture of `[`/`test` and `==`, which a bash extension. Other shells do not support `==`. To make this script more portable, you should use:

```
if [ "$threshold_type" = "above" ]
```

Bash supports `==` in both `[` and `[[` constructs but `=` is the POSIX-compliant (correct) way to do the comparison.

Comment: True, but `==` would produce an error, not simply return false.

Comment: @chepner fair enough, I don't have much experience with shells other than bash so I didn't know that. If it's impossible that this is the solution, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Here's the error I get in `dash`: $ if [ foo == bar ]; then echo huh; fi
dash: 1: [: foo: unexpected operator

Comment: @TomFenech I'll be darned, the single equals sign did the trick.  Odd, given I'm running the bash shell in both enviroments (echo $SHELL) but I'll take it.

Comment: @larryq glad it worked out, I wasn't sure that it would but thought it was worth a try still :)